# Usar conekta en aplicación ionic-angular

Tags: angular, ionic, cordova

Estoy intentando usar el sdk javascript de conekta para tokenizar la tarjeta y con las llaves de desarrollo no tengo problemas, pero al utilizar las llaves de producción me marca el siguiente error:

```
{
"object": "error",
"type": "protocol_error",
"message": "Connection must be secured in production",
"message_to_purchaser": "La conexión tiene que ser segura en producción",
"param": null,
"code": "",
"validation_error": null                                                                             
}
```

---

Mi versión de ionic es la siguiente:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.10
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.0

Cordova:


   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0, ios 5.1.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 23 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res (update available: 0.15.2) : 0.8.1
   native-run (update available: 1.3.0)   : 0.3.0

System:

   NodeJS : v12.14.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.13.4
   OS     : Windows 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo tenía el mismo problema, me comuniqué con soporte de conekta y esta fue su respuesta, espero te sirva (:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, también acabo de encontrar una solución que es agregar en el archivo config.xml la etiqueta `<preference name="Scheme" value="https" />`, y con esto al momento de compilarlo te lo hace bajo https y de esta forma ya se puede tokenizar la tarjeta.

Comment: Como exactamente se agrega el <preference mame="Scheme" value=https"> , lo agregue en config.xml pero la falla persiste.